# ScrollTo animation react-spring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, react-hooks, react-spring

As per title, all I'm trying to achieve is to scroll to some element smoothly by using `react-spring` animations.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-examples-forked-z72o2?file=/index.js) I reproduced a snippet with a working example (which when clicking on a section brings you to the following one); Problem is this works only on versions below `v6.0.0`.

As you can notice on `index.js`, I added a commented line with a component which contains the exact same logic but converted to `v9.1.2` (which doesn't work).

So question is, what part did I convert wrongly? I am probably missing some bits from breaking changes on `v6` and I tried looking into the documentation, but they reference to breaking changes for `v8` and `v9` only, so I'm a bit confused on what I'm missing?

Any answer with a working solution it's perfectly fine, doesn't need to be based on my example - big thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version `9.1.2` seems to have some bugs which might be causing this. I found [an issue](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-spring/issues/1517) which also states the same problems. (Also, [the original issue that found this](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-spring/issues/1454))

So, according to their [releases](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-spring/releases/tag/v9.2.0), version `9.2.0` or upwards would have this issue fixed. I tried `9.2.1` (latest at the time of this answer) in the sandbox provided in the question and it works:

[Forked Sandbox (working)](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-examples-forked-koo5i?file=/index.js)